# No declaration found for element XML / XSD

Tags: html, xml, xsd

I am very new to XML and I am facing issues with validation and also would like some feedback if my XML and XSD files are well structured.

I am constantly getting the error when validating the XML against the XSD ->  **No declaration found for element xs:schema.**

I'm using the program XML copy editor on windows. 
I also tried on an online validator XML against XSD and got this error. https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html

I get error **Src-resolve: Cannot Resolve The Name 'string' To A(n) 'type Definition' Component.**

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<alumnos>
        <alumno>
            <nombre>Samuel</nombre>
            <apellido>Van Bladel</apellido>
            <email>Samuelvanbladel@gmail.com</email>
            <foto>google.com</foto> 
            <expediente>NX-0001R</expediente>
            <curso>1</curso> 
            <modulo>Mark up languages
            <nota>10/10</nota>
            <comentario>Muy bien hecho hasta el techo.</comentario>
            </modulo>
            <modulo>Java
            <nota>9/10</nota>
            <comentario>Codigo muy bien structurada.</comentario>
            </modulo>
        </alumno>

        <alumno>
            <nombre>Deniz</nombre>
            <apellido>Turki</apellido>
            <email>DenizTurki@gmail.com</email>
            <foto>google.com</foto> 
            <expediente>NX-0002R</expediente>
            <curso>2</curso> 
            <modulo>Mark up languages
            <nota>10/10</nota>
            <comentario>Muy bien hecho hasta el techo.</comentario>
            </modulo>
            <modulo>Java
            <nota>9/10</nota>
            <comentario>Codigo muy bien structurada.</comentario>
            </modulo>
        </alumno>

        <alumno>
            <nombre>Denisa</nombre>
            <apellido>Hermann</apellido>
            <email>Denisahermann@gmail.com</email>
            <foto>google.com</foto> 
            <expediente>NX-0003R</expediente>
            <curso>3</curso> 
            <modulo>Mark up languages
            <nota>10/10</nota>
            <comentario>Muy bien hecho hasta el techo.</comentario>
            </modulo>
            <modulo>Java
            <nota>9/10</nota>
            <comentario>Codigo muy bien structurada.</comentario>
            </modulo>
        </alumno>

        <alumno>
            <nombre>Bruno</nombre>
            <apellido>porto</apellido>
            <email>BrunoPorto@gmail.com</email>
            <foto>google.com</foto> 
            <expediente>NX-0004R</expediente>
            <curso>4</curso> 
            <modulo>Mark up languages
            <nota>10/10</nota>
            <comentario>Muy bien hecho hasta el techo.</comentario>
            </modulo>
            <modulo>Java
            <nota>9/10</nota>
            <comentario>Codigo muy bien structurada.</comentario>
            </modulo>
        </alumno>

</alumnos>
```

XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<!-- definition of simple elements -->
                    <xs:element name="nombre">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                          <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9]{20}"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>

                    <xs:element name="apellido">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                          <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9]{30}"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>

                    <xs:element name="comentario">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                          <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9]{50}"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>

                    <xs:element name="modulo">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                          <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>

                    <xs:element name="nota"  >
                      <xs:simpleType>
                         <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                           <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{8}"/>
                         </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>

                    <xs:element name="email"> 
                        <xs:simpleType > 
                          <xs:restriction base="xs:string"> 
                            <xs:pattern value="[^@]+@[^\.]+\..+"/> 
                          </xs:restriction> 
                        </xs:simpleType> 
                    </xs:element>

                    <xs:element name="foto">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:anyURI">
                            <xs:pattern value="http://.+" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>

                    <xs:element name="expediente">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="string">
                            <xs:pattern value="NX + [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] + R"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>


<!-- definition of attributes -->
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>

<!-- definition of complex elements -->

    <xs:element name="alumno">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="nombre"/>
                <xs:element ref="apellido"/>
                <xs:element ref="modulo"/>
                <xs:element ref="nota"/>     
                <xs:element ref="expediente"/> 
                <xs:element ref="foto"/> 
                <xs:element ref="email"/>
                <xs:element ref="comentario"/>
            </xs:sequence>    
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>


  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: `base="string"` needs to be replaced with `base="xs:string"`, which solves the immediate problem you are seeing. There might be others.

Answer (score 1):

The error "No declaration found for element xs:schema." means that you're trying to validate the schema rather than the instance document. You haven't said how you are invoking the validation, but I suspect that in whatever API you are using, you've got the schema and the source document the wrong way around.